# Winforms user control getting clipped when in another user control (sometimes)

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2005

The problem is fairly simple, but is best illustrated visually.  Note that all screen shots are from the Visual Studio 2005 design surface.  I've noticed no difference when I actually run the application.

Here is my user control (let's call this UC-1):

[image]

The buttons on the control are set to anchor to Bottom + Right.

Here is what it looks like when placed onto a particular parent user control (UC-A):

[image]

Please disregard the difference in colors and such.  Some styling is done in the user control's constructor.

Notice the bottom of the control is getting clipped.  The instance of the consumed control on the parent is set with a "FixedSingle" border.  Notice also that the consumed control is taller than the original, indicating that the buttons bottom anchor settings are being respected, but are essentially overshooting where it should be.

To confirm this is definitely a problem on the parent control, notice another user control (UC-2) containing a data grid view when placed on the same parent:

[image]

Again, the instance of the consumed control is set with a "FixedSingle" border which helps illustrate the clipping.  The datagrid is properly anchored to the Bottom Right.  To reinforce the perplexity of this problem, here's the first user control (UC-1) when placed on a different parent user control (UC-B):

[alt text http://i38.tinypic.com/2rnyjd0.png](http://i38.tinypic.com/2rnyjd0.png)

Here's the second "consumed" control (UC-2) when consumed by a form:

[image]

Notice, no clipping this time.

I have spent many hours searching and experimenting to resolve this.  I have exhausted the various settings of margins, padding, sizes (min/max), locations, anchors... etc.  I can not for the life of me figure out why this one user control is causing child user controls to clip like this.

Another strange thing I noticed was that when I do an UNDO on the parent user control design surface (where the controls are misbehaving), the clipped user control instances actually shift location even though the undo action is unrelated to those controls.  For example, if I make the main containing control larger, then undo, a couple of the child user controls jump up.  They appear to move about as far as they are being clipped.  Very suspicious.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on??

Comment: No. This was a problem in a project from last year that I have not worked on in about as long. As it was a design time issue, it wasn't much of concern after we got things working so I haven't given it any more thought.

Answer (score 1):

A very interesting problem!

Does your problem parent (UC-A) override any of the methods around sizing or client areas?

Or has UC-A got a negative value for the bottom value of Padding or Margin ?

Is there anything else docked at the bottom edge of UC-A? Perhaps, something that has a negative size?

Or, does UC-A set the constraints of its child controls? If the minimum height of the panel is forced too large, you would get this result.

Hope this is helpful! If not, is there any chance you post the source to UC-A ?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the exact same problem and found your post while searching for a possible solution. Although I'm pretty sure that this is a bug in winforms, I found a bit of a workaround. Just put everything in your user control inside a panel, dock the panel to full, and do your anchoring inside the panel. This seems to alleviate the problem, although my button does tend up to show up at a slightly different size than it should in the parent control. Very weird. I compensated by making the button smaller in the designer, and it stretches wider by a few pixels in the parent control for some unknown reason. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the parent control in question is not a standard .NET framework type, but a custom one, I'd guess that it is mixing up client and screen co-ordinates somewhere in it's logic. But that's just a guess.